# Springboot get username from Authentication via Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

**Problem:**
I would like to get/extract the username/email only from authenticate.getName()... if possible, not by using parsing the string.

**authentication.getName() or principal.getName() values:**

```
[username]: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@21463e7a: Username: butitoy@iyotbihagay.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities
```

*In this example, I would like to get only the value of Username which is butitoy@iyotbihagay.com*

**Solution:**

Since I only want to get the username/email (butitoy@iyotbihagay.com), and it is returning the whole principal content/text (above), I replaced the value I set in the subject from the pricipal value... to the email value.. and it works now.

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                        HttpServletResponse res,
                                        FilterChain chain,
                                        Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String email = auth.getName();
    String principal = auth.getPrincipal().toString();
    Date expiration = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME);
    String token = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(email) //from principal to email
            .setExpiration(expiration)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SecurityConstants.SECRET.getBytes())
            .compact();
    AuthenticatedUser loginUser = new AuthenticatedUser(email);
    loginUser.setToken(token);
    String jsonUser = Util.objectToJsonResponseAsString(loginUser, "user");
    res.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    res.setContentType("application/json");
    res.setCharacterEncoding(ConstantUtil.DEFAULT_ENCODING);
    res.getWriter().write(jsonUser);
}
```

I can now get the username/email value using different ways like the one you guys are suggesting... even the one I am currently using. I do not need any special parsing now just to get the email value from the Authentication object.

On my previous non RESTful application using Spring... I can easily get the username using Authentication class injected in the controller method parameter.

**Controller:**

```
...  
public Ticket getBySwertresNo(Authentication authentication, @PathVariable String swertresNo) {  
    logger.debug("Inside getBySwertresNo: " + swertresNo);  
    System.out.println("\n[username]: " + authentication.getName() + "\n");  
    return m_sugalService.getSwertresInfoBySwertresNo(swertresNo);  
}  
...
```

**Console:**

```
[username]: butitoy@iyotbihagay.com
```

Now, on my current project... I used a RESTful approach and after successful authentication, I am returning a token which will be used/injected in the request header. I can login using the token... but when I get the value of authentication.getName()... the return is not just the email address but it contains some other information.

**Console (REST + JWT):**

```
[username]: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@21463e7a: Username: butitoy@iyotbihagay.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities
```

I would like to get only the username value which is "butitoy@iyotbihagay.com".

**JWT Authentication Filter:**

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = req.getParameter("username");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
        return authentication;
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String email = auth.getName();
        String principal = auth.getPrincipal().toString();
        Date expiration = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME);
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(principal)
                .setExpiration(expiration)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SecurityConstants.SECRET.getBytes())
                .compact();
        AuthenticatedUser loginUser = new AuthenticatedUser(email);
        loginUser.setToken(token);
        String jsonUser = Util.objectToJsonResponseAsString(loginUser, "user");
        res.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
        res.setContentType("application/json");
        res.setCharacterEncoding(ConstantUtil.DEFAULT_ENCODING);
        res.getWriter().write(jsonUser);
    }

}
```

**JWT Authorization Filter:**

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse res,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SecurityConstants.SECRET.getBytes())
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();

            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: why don't yo put a break point in your controller and inspect the value of Authentication object?

Comment: Just wanted to note that RESTfulness has nothing to do with whether you use JWT or not.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I am new to REST btw.. I tried debugging the controller but I am getting the whole long string value not the separated strings.

Comment: you are getting the entire object, because that is what you are passing into the: String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(principal). You can change that to use email, or just go with username and then do a lookup later for that user.

Comment: @BorgyManotoy Any update to this?

Answer (score 28):

I think you can use `authentication.getName` and `principal.getName` in the injected controller argument of type `Authentication` and `Principal`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/info")
public class GetNameController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/name", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getName(Authentication authentication, Principal principal) {
        System.out.println(authentication.getName());
        System.out.println("-----------------");
        System.out.println(principal.getName());
        return "";
    }
}
```

could produce

```
admin
-----------------
admin
```

Comment: Same results: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@21463e7a: Username: butitoy@iyotbihagay.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities

Answer (score 15):

It doesn't matter whether you are using token or basic spring security authentication as far as Authentication/Principal object is concerned.

In case of spring security, you can get your current logged in user by
1. `Object user = Authentication authentication` (as you are already doing) 
2.

```
Object user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
                    .getPrincipal();
```

In both cases, `user` will contains the user object you returning from `UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(...)`. So using default `UserDetailsService` you will get spring security's `User` object which contains basic user information like `username`, `password` etc.

So in case if you are using default spring's `UserDetailsService`, then you can get your current logged in user simply by

```
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
                        .getPrincipal();
String username = userDetails.getUsername();
```

Comment: Cannot cast to User

Answer (score 4):

You can use

> import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
>
> import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();



   System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------");
    JwtUser jwtUser = (JwtUser) auth.getPrincipal();
    
    //Get the username of the logged in user: getPrincipal()
    System.out.println("auth.getPrincipal()=>"+jwtUser.getUsername() );
    //Get the password of the authenticated user: getCredentials()
    System.out.println("auth.getCredentials()=>"+auth.getCredentials());
    //Get the assigned roles of the authenticated user: getAuthorities()
    System.out.println("auth.getAuthorities()=>"+auth.getAuthorities());
    //Get further details of the authenticated user: getDetails()
    System.out.println("auth.getDetails()=>"+auth.getDetails());
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------");
```

Answer (score -1):

Have not seen so far any accepted answer, maybe this will help:

use `JwtTokenUtils.debugPrint();` call from below class. For other token payload see what is available inside `tokenMap`.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.security.jwt.JwtHelper;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidTokenException;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

import static org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AccessTokenConverter.EXP;

public class JwtTokenUtils {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtTokenUtils.class);
    private static Format dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void debugPrint() {
        try {
            Map<String, Object>  tokenMap = decode(getToken());
            logger.debug("JwtTokenUtils:debugPrint jwt:"
                    + " user_name {" + tokenMap.get("user_name")
                    + "}, expired {" + convertTime((long)tokenMap.get(EXP))
                    + "}");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("JwtTokenUtils:debugPrint exception: " + e);
        }
    }

    private static String getToken() {
        return getAuthorizationHeader().split(" ")[1];
    }

    private static String getAuthorizationHeader() {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        return request.getHeader("Authorization");
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> decode(String token) {
        try {
            Jwt jwt = JwtHelper.decode(token);
            String claimsStr = jwt.getClaims();
            TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<>() {};
            return objectMapper.readValue(claimsStr, typeRef); 
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new InvalidTokenException("Cannot convert access token to JSON", e);
        }
    }

    private static String convertTime(long time){
        Date date = new Date(time * 1000);
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
}
```