# Spring with JWT auth, get current user

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I have Spring Boot REST application which uses JWT tokens for authorization. I want to get current logged user in controllers using `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation. But it always returns `null` if i return custom model from `loadUserByUsername` and auth stop working. My model implements `UserDetails`.

I tried to extend the `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` but i get rid errors from **JWTAuthenticationFilter** that default constructor not exists (`ApplicationUser creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), ApplicationUser.class);`)

Whats wrong?

**UserDetailsServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (applicationUser == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);

        return applicationUser;
    }
}
```

**ApplicationUser.java (model)**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class ApplicationUser implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**JWTAuthenticationFilter**

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(LOGIN_URL));

        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            ApplicationUser creds = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), ApplicationUser.class);

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getUsername(),
                            creds.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>())
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(((ApplicationUser) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET.getBytes())
                .compact();

        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }
}
```

**JWTAuthorizationFilter**

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse res,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user;
            try {
                user = Jwts.parser()
                        .setSigningKey(SECRET.getBytes())
                        .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                        .getBody()
                        .getSubject();
            } catch (SignatureException e) {
                return null;
            }

            if (user != null) return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());

            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: anyone reading this in 2023, the type of authentication displayed above has been deemed very insecure, you should never hand out JWTs to browsers anymore as there are multiple vulnerabilities attached to it. Do not use the above code to any type of production applications.

Answer (score 3):

I recently implemented a method to get the username or email from the JWT token in SpringBoot. Sharing the experience

```
private String getUserName() {
         JwtAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = (JwtAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    Jwt jwt = (Jwt) authenticationToken.getCredentials();
    String email = (String) jwt.getClaims().get("email");
    return email;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this good experience.

Answer (score 2):

In your case the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` will return a string with the username,
you can get the user by calling the repository in your controller and getting the user by the username or declaring the repository as a `@Bean` and do the folowing:

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

//Get the repository
private UserRepository userRepository;

public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
    super(authManager);
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                HttpServletResponse res,
                                FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

    if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        return;
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
    if (token != null) {
        // parse the token.
        String user;
        try {
            user = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SECRET.getBytes())
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            return null;
        }

        //Get your user
        UserEntity userEntity = this.userRepository.findByUsername(user);

        if (user != null) {
             //Seting in your AuthenticationPrincipal the user
             return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userEntity, null, new ArrayList<>());
        }

        return null;
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are using suitable annotation, because one of them is deprecated.

[Documentation - deprecated!](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/bind/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipal.html)

[Documentation - fine!](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipal.html)

---

In addition, be aware to resolve username (String) as an argument, not User type:

> Annotation that is used to resolve Authentication.getPrincipal() to a method argument.

[Check this topic as well!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616386/spring-security-authenticationprincipal) It can help.

---

I don't know if it is good practice (I'm not considered 'pro' in Spring yet), but in my personal project I get token from HttpServletRequest object passed in controller parameter. Then I use JwtTokenUtil class, which have `getUserFormToken(String token);` method to resolve user/username. It looks like this:

### Controller

```
@Autowired
TestService testService;

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@Autowired
private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<Test> getTestsListByUserId(HttpServletRequest req){
    String token = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING).replace(TOKEN_PREFIX,"");
    return testService.findByUserId(userService.findByUsername(jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(token)));
}
```

### JwtTokenUtil

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil implements Serializable {

public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
    return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
}

public Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
    return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration);
}

public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
    final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
    return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
}

private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
    return Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(SIGNING_KEY)
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();
}

private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
    final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
    return expiration.before(new Date());
}

public String generateToken(User user) {
    return doGenerateToken(user.getUsername());
}

private String doGenerateToken(String subject) {

    Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(subject);
    claims.put("scopes", Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")));

    return Jwts.builder()
            .setClaims(claims)
            .setIssuer("issuer")
            .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS*1000))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, SIGNING_KEY)
            .compact();
}

public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
    final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
    return (
           username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())
                   && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }

}
```

But I generally have different filters implementation according yo yours. If you are interested - I used [this](https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-boot-jwt-auth) tutorial and implementation.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve a custom model i do next things:

Get model from Database and set it as Principal.

```
 private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user;
            try {
                user = Jwts.parser()
                        .setSigningKey(SECRET.getBytes())
                        .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                        .getBody()
                        .getSubject();
            } catch (SignatureException e) {
                return null;
            }

            // Get user model
            ApplicationUser userModel = userRepository.findByUsername(user);

            // Set it
            if (user != null && userModel != null) return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userModel, null, new ArrayList<>());

            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Then in controller retrieve using `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation.

```
public ApplicationUser getCurrentUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal ApplicationUser user) {
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is still actual, I have just answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55850687/1070842)

Main point is to take `authorization token` from header:

```
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    String token = request.getHeader("Authorization").split(" ")[1];
```

after that you can decode it and get parts which you need.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can do this, its easily and more simple :

```
public User getCurrentUser() {
        Authentication authenticationToken = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return (User)authenticationToken.getPrincipal();
    }
```