# What is the best way accessing username from request

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I am developing a simple todo application with Spring Boot. I am using JWT for authorisation. All todos belongs to a user will be get with following endpoint.

```
@GetMapping("")
public List<Todo> todos(){
    //get username from token
    //return todos belongs to user
}
```

I have two problems in here:

1. Is getting username from token a good practise?
2. What is the best way accessing username with token from a controller class or a service class?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54911059) shows how to reach token from controller class.
but what if we want to reach token from service class? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54911617) shows it. But the class is deprecated.

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529760/springboot-get-username-from-authentication-via-controller

Answer (score 0):

you can get username like this:

```
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
                        .getPrincipal();
String username = userDetails.getUsername();
```

Comment: Please dont copy answers from other places, and paste them.

Comment: i wanted to but i couldnt..im new